# Memory runs out and application stops working

Tags: android, memory, firebase

I have been coding multiplayer game with Firebase through Android Studio and wanted the players to be able to open servers. When I clicked on Create Button, the application should create new Server and put the player in it and then open the activity of the server, but I have a problem with the memory and I can't find what is the real cause.

Problem note: (repeats very fast and application stops responding)

```
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8190K, 23% free 27797K/36044K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
```

After some research, I managed to find that this piece of code is probably the cause of this problem, but I have no idea how to fix it/what is the real cause.

```
serversRef.child("S"+id).child("id").setValue(id);
serversRef.child("S"+id).child("name").setValue(serverNameEt.getText().toString());
if(serverPasswordEt.getText().toString().equals(""))
   serversRef.child("S"+id).child("password").setValue("~");
else
   serversRef.child("S"+id).child("password").setValue(serverPasswordEt.getText().toString());
serversRef.child("S"+id).child("isJoinable").setValue(true);
serversRef.child("S"+id).child("isCustom").setValue(true);
serversRef.child("S"+id).child("gameState").setValue("pregame");
serversRef.child("S"+id).child("question").setValue("please wait for players");
serversRef.child("S"+id).child("roundsToWin").setValue(slotsSb.getProgress() + 5);
serversRef.child("S"+id).child("slots").setValue(slotsSb.getProgress() + 3);
CustomUser customUser = new CustomUser(false, currentUser.getUsername(), "answer", 0, currentUser.getWins(), 0);
serversRef.child("S"+id).child("player0").setValue(customUser);
Intent intent = new Intent(ServerSetupActivity.this,ServerActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("currentUser",currentUser);
intent.putExtra("serverNum",id);
Log.d("startingActivity","ID"+id);
startActivity(intent);
```

The Firebase data is added well and If other users try to join the server it works for them.

**EDIT**

after some further investigation it seems like even one line with setValue will cause this problem here, but anywhere else in the app it works well...

Comment: This message `D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8190K, 23% free 27797K/36044K, paused 14ms, total 14ms` implicitly means that you have a very heavy task being executed on main UI thread.

Comment: That message isn't necessarily the reason why the app closed, like @AmitUpadhyay said. You should post the Exception StackTrace from your logcat